# Several UIAlertViews for a delegate

Tags: ios, iphone, delegates, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

Currently I've got a class popping up `UIAlertView`s here and there. Currently, the same class is the delegate for these (it's very logical that it would be). Unfortunately, these `UIAlertView`s will call the same delegate methods of the class. Now, the question is - how do you know from which alert view a delegate method is invoked? I was thinking of just checking the title of the alert view, but that isn't so elegant. What's the most elegant way to handle several `UIAlertView`s?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Tag the `UIAlertView`s like this:

```
#define kAlertViewOne 1
#define kAlertViewTwo 2

UIAlertView *alertView1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...
alertView1.tag = kAlertViewOne;

UIAlertView *alertView2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...
alertView2.tag = kAlertViewTwo;
```

and then differentiate between them in the delegate methods using these tags:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView.tag == kAlertViewOne) {
        // ...
    } else if(alertView.tag == kAlertViewTwo) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, nice. Though I'd use a switch. :)

Comment: of course a switch would work too, but I never liked switch. =)

Comment: Great answer.  But that leads me to another question.  Why do you define the kAlertViewOne 1 and kAlertViewRwo 2.  Couldn't you just use in the alertView.tag = 1 or alertView.tag = 2?

Is this done for a reason?

Comment: kAlertViewOne and kAlertViewTwo make more sense than 1 or 2. for example, in your question, you can use kAlertResume and kAlertRetry, and they'd be more readable than two random numbers.

Comment: Is there a reason you would not have them strings?

Comment: tag is defined as an NSInteger.

Comment: FYI, assigning tags the numbers less than 10 might conflict with those Apple rarely uses.

Comment: Incidentally you can cast a NSString * into a NSInteger and read it back later. However that may be too kludgy for some.

Answer (score 4):

FYI, if you want to target just iOS 4 users (which is reasonable [now that ~98.5% of clients have at least iOS 4 installed](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper)), you should be able to use Blocks to do really nice inline handling of UIAlertViews.

Here's a Stackoverflow question explaining it:
[Block for UIAlertViewDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082383/block-for-uialertviewdelegate)

I tried using Zachary Waldowski's BlocksKit framework for this.  His [UIAlertView(BlocksKit) API](http://zwaldowski.github.com/BlocksKit/Documentation/Categories/UIAlertView+BlocksKit.html#//api/name/showAlertViewWithTitle:message:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:handler:) reference looked really good.  However, I tried to follow [his instructions to import the BlocksKit framework](http://zwaldowski.github.com/BlocksKit/Documentation/) into my project, but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work.

So, as Can Berk Güder suggests, I've used `UIAlertView` tags for now.  But at some point in future I'm going to try to move to using Blocks (preferably one which supports ARC out of the box)!

Comment: If you're using iOS 8+, UIAlertController has block based delegate methods.

Answer (score 3):

easier & newer

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...
alert.tag = 1;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...
alert.tag = 2;



- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if(alertView.tag == 1) {
        // first alert...
    } else  {
        // sec alert...
    }
}
```

all done!

Answer (score 1):

You can overcome this whole ordeal and prevent yourself from using tags by enhancing UIAlertView to use block callbacks. Check out [this blog post](http://stavash.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/quick-tip-uialertview-with-a-block-callback/) I wrote on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought using tags is a bit of a hack. If you do use them, at least set some defined constants for the tag numbers.

Instead, I use properties like this:

In the interface section:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIAlertView *overDueAlertView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIAlertView *retryPromptAlertView;
```

Creating the alert view:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] init...
self.overDueAlertView = alert;
[alert show];
```

Delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if (alertView == self.overDueAlertView) {
    // Overdue alert
  } else if (alertView == self.retryPromptAlertView) {
    // Retry alert
  }
```