# Block for UIAlertViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm pretty new to objective C and I'm just trying to figure out if I can use a block or a selector as the UIAlertViewDelegate argument for UIAlertView - and which is more appropriate?

I've tried the following but it just isn't working so I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not?

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Checked In" 
    message:responseString
    delegate:^(UIAlertView * alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex)
                                                    {
                                                       NSLog(@"Done!");
                                                   } 
    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
    otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Apple doesn't offer it , but it's a good idea.  The way to do it is a subclass.  I'll make one real quick and post it.

Comment: danh's answer works but it does not support multiple buttons. See my answer below.

Answer (score 28):

Great idea.  Here it is.  Just like alert view, except adds a block property that's invoked when the alert is dismissed.  (Edit - I've simplified this code since the original answer.  Here's what I use now in projects)

```
//  AlertView.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AlertView : UIAlertView

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^completion)(BOOL, NSInteger);

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles;

@end

//
//  AlertView.m

#import "AlertView.h"

@interface AlertView () <UIAlertViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation AlertView

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles {

    self = [self initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];

    if (self) {
        for (NSString *buttonTitle in otherButtonTitles) {
            [self addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (self.completion) {
        self.completion(buttonIndex==self.cancelButtonIndex, buttonIndex);
        self.completion = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

You can extend this idea to supply blocks for other delegate methods, but the didDismiss is the most common.

Call it like this:

```
AlertView *alert = [[AlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really Delete" message:@"Do you really want to delete everything?" cancelButtonTitle:@"Nevermind" otherButtonTitles:@[@"Yes"]];

alert.completion = ^(BOOL cancelled, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
    if (!cancelled) {
        [self deleteEverything];
    }
};
[alert show];
```

Comment: Here's a (fuller) implementation of danh's idea: http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/ios-code-block-based-uialertview-and-uiactionsheet/

Comment: Have you tried to add multiple buttons? `:-)` see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks @Besi.  Updated the answer to incorporate your code properly handling var args.

Comment: Unless I'm overlooking something, you're not using the `cancelButtonTitle` parameter. It would also be useful to have the alert itself as an argument to the block (as in the delegate method), so that the button index can be compared with `alert.cancelButtonIndex`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing your first point, but the cancelButtonTitle is passed through to the native init.  As for the self param to the block, I think this is better suited to the delegate pattern than the block.  It needs to be a weak copy to avoid a retain cycle.  But the cancelButtonIndex as a param might be a good addition.

Comment: Thanks @omz.  Passing a bool to indicate cancellation.

Comment: @danh I'm having trouble with the `__bridge` cast. Would it be wrong to `va_args(_arguments, NSString *)`? That compiles. Working in ARC. Error is "Error after macro substitution: __bridge requires CF pointer type instead of 'id'"

Comment: It looks like I accepted somebody's edit that contained the cast.  Maybe it was pre-ARC.  I'll re-edit now.

Comment: Category for UIAlertView with block. https://github.com/GuyKahlon/UIAlertView-CompletionBlocks.git

Comment: Looking into passing a data object into the alert so that it can be processed with the block.

Answer (score 2):

One must use UIAlertController for that approach as Apple document says

> A UIAlertController object displays an alert message to the user. This
>   class replaces the UIActionSheet and UIAlertView classes for
>   displaying alerts. After configuring the alert controller with the
>   actions and style you want, present it using the
>   presentViewController:animated:completion: method.
>
> In addition to displaying a message to a user, you can associate
>   actions with your alert controller to give the user a way to respond.
>   For each action you add using the addAction: method, the alert
>   controller configures a button with the action details. When the user
>   taps that action, the alert controller executes the block you provided
>   when creating the action object.
>   [Apple Docs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html)

```
UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Alert"


       message:@"This is an alert."
                                   preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [UIAlertView-Blocks](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks) category on github. I use this and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an update to danh's implementation, which is incomplete because it is not possible to add multiple buttons. Passing a va_list to a function is a little tricky :-)

So you could do this, in order to be able to add multiple buttons to the `UIAlertView`:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message completion:(void (^)(NSInteger buttonIndex))completion cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... {

    self = [super initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil ];


    if(self){
        _completion = completion;

        va_list _arguments;
        va_start(_arguments, otherButtonTitles);

        for (NSString *key = otherButtonTitles; key != nil; key = (__bridge NSString *)va_arg(_arguments, void *)) {
                [self addButtonWithTitle:key];
        }
        va_end(_arguments);

    }

    return self;
}
```

**Update**: There might be a better way of passing the va_list to `super`. I would like to mention that to me `va_list`s have something mystic to them :-)

Comment: That's a good catch.  Thanks for the va arg tips.  I'll edit my answer in case this one is missed.

Answer (score 1):

Awesome idea. I have just completed exactly your idea using Category pattern, no subclass, call directly UIAlertView. Please follow these steps:

1. Category UIAlertView in .h file

   ```
   @interface UIAlertView (AlertWithBlock)

      - (void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegateBlock;
      - (void)setDelegateBlock:(void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegateBlock;

      + (id)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString   *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles delegate:(void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegate;

   @end
   ```
2. In .m file

   ```
   @implementation UIAlertView(AlertWithBlock)

   static char const *delegateBlockTagKey = "delegateBlockTagKey";

   - (void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegateBlock
   {
       return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, delegateBlockTagKey);
   }

   - (void)setDelegateBlock:(void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegateBlock
   {
       objc_setAssociatedObject(self, delegateBlockTagKey, delegateBlock, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
   }

   + (id)alertWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSArray *)otherButtonTitles delegate:(void (^)(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex))delegate
   {
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:nil];
       alert.delegate = alert;
       alert.delegateBlock = [delegate copy];

       for (NSString *buttonTitle in otherButtonTitles)
       {
           [alert addButtonWithTitle:buttonTitle];
       }

       [alert show];

       return alert;
   }

   #pragma mark - Delegate
   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
   {
       if (alertView.delegateBlock)
       {
           alertView.delegateBlock(alertView, buttonIndex);
       }
   }

   @end
   ```
3. Call like this

   ```
   [UIAlertView alertWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"This is a message" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@[@"Yes",@"No"] delegate:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSInteger buttonIndex) {
   NSLog(@"Click at button index %ld", buttonIndex);
   }];
   ```

Hope it help.

Comment: Nice!  Don;t forget #import <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score 1):

I have written a simple extension in Swift, hope it helpful

```
import UIKit

extension UIAlertView {

    func show(completion: (alertView: UIAlertView, buttonIndex: Int) -> Void){
        self.delegate = AlertViewDelegate(completion: completion)
        self.show()
    }

    class func showInput(title: String?, message: String?, cancellable: Bool, completion: (text: String?) -> Void){

        var strOK = NSLocalizedString("OK",comment: "OK")
        var strCancel = NSLocalizedString("Cancel",comment: "Cancel")
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: cancellable ? strCancel : strOK)
        alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
        if(cancellable) {
            alert.addButtonWithTitle(strOK)
        }
        alert.show { (alertView, buttonIndex) -> Void in
            if(cancellable && alertView.cancelButtonIndex == buttonIndex) {
                completion(text: nil)
                return
            }
            completion(text: alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text)
        }
    }

    private class AlertViewDelegate : NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate {
        var completion :  (alertView: UIAlertView, buttonIndex: Int) -> Void
        var retainedSelf : NSObject?
        init(completion: (UIAlertView, Int) -> Void ) {
            self.completion = completion
            super.init()

            self.retainedSelf = self
        }

        func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, didDismissWithButtonIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
            var retain = self
            retain.retainedSelf = nil
            retain.completion(alertView: alertView, buttonIndex: buttonIndex)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, seems like it's similar to most answers here:
http://stavash.wordpress.com/2013/01/31/quick-tip-uialertview-with-a-block-callback/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [REKit](https://github.com/zuccoi/REKit). It's similar to BlocksKit, but it's more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [UIAlertView-Blocks category on Github](https://github.com/GuyKahlon/UIAlertView-CompletionBlocks.git).
I wrote this and is very easy to use and works well.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another useful library to do the same. http://bit.ly/ichalrtvw

Code here: http://bit.ly/ichalertview

Answer (score -2):

I had to edit the calling example a bit to stop complier error.  Just a small tweak and xcode was happy.

```
UIAlertViewBlock *alert = [[UIAlertViewBlock alloc] initWithTitle:@"hi"
                                                          message:@"hi there"
                                                       completion:^(BOOL canceled,NSInteger buttonIndex) {
                                                           NSLog(@"canceled=%d", canceled);
                                                           NSLog(@"pressed=%d", buttonIndex);
                                                       }
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
[alert show];
```