# Is it a good practice to use tags in-order to handle multiple UIAlertViews, each with their own buttons and actions?

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have multiple UIAlertViews, each having unique buttons and actions. Is it a good practice to use tags in-order to handle multiple UIAlertViews ?

Comment: yes, but with the help of different different button you can manage there actions.

Comment: No. It is not since `UIAlertView` has been deprecated for years. Use `UIAlertController`. No tags needed.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks. But we had to support from iOS 7 onwards, which doesn't support UIAlertController. Anyhow going forward, as Apple is strictly going to remove the 32Bit support, we have take off the support for iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good discussion regarding this in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338546/several-uialertviews-for-a-delegate)
I am assuming that you are using this for an older iOS as it is deprecated by `UIAlertController`.

Comment: Yes correct @rmaddy. Thanks for sharing the post. I will check this.

Comment: @scorpion I think you meant to reply to Mukund, not me. He posted this answer.